# With MSDeploy... how can you publish Web.QA.config => Web.config

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, publish, msdeploy

This seems rather basic... but I cannot figure out how to do this... when I publish a Visual Studio project to my staging server (qa) I have a Web.QA.config file that contains all the transforms for database connections, etc... for my QA environment. I would have assumed the simple way would be to change something in my QA.pubxml file. Then if I right click my project and choose publish then QA... it would use use Web.QA.config as Web.config... any help?

Comment: Have you already used the Configuration Manager to set up a QA configuration? You may be missing that step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, MSDeploy will apply the Web.{configuration}.config transformation file to the Web.config that matches the build configuration name.

For simple projects, this means that the easiest way to apply environment-specific transformations is to rename the default build configurations "Debug" and "Release" to the name of your lowest and highest environments, then clone the lowest or highest environment configuration and name the clone(s) the middle environment name(s), if needed.

From there you just need to ensure that your publish profile uses the matching build configuration.

For more complicated projects, you might take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/transform-webconfig?view=aspnetcore-2.2.  This is for aspnetcore, but the information contained is still applicable to .NET Framework.

Comment: This is what I would have expected... but oddly when I publish with  my QA configuraton... I still see: 16>Transformed Web.config using E:\projects\ssptrades\DataCollector_Fix\Web.Release.config into obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.

Comment: I think you might be making a common misunderstanding of Visual Studio's publish UI. The solution configuration drop down, which is next to the start debugging button, doesn't actually affect the configuration that is being published. Try this:  click the cog wheel next to the publish button with your QA publish profile selected.  This will open a publish tab (in 2019) that has a Summary section.  In that section you should see a "Configuration" property that is presumably set to "Release" still.  You can change it using the pencil next to that text.

Comment: It could also be that you renamed the solution's configuration name without renaming the project's configuration name.  In this case it will uses the project's configuration name.